# Impersonating user in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following piece of code from a regular mvc app which uploads a file by impersonating a user

```
 public class PublicController : Controller
 {
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    

    public SomeActionMethod(model containing file)
    {
       if (ImpersonateValidUser(userName: "someuserwithpowertoupload", domain: "", password: "somepassword"))
       {
        path = "Somepath";
        file.SaveAs(path);
       }
    }


 private bool ImpersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, impersonationLevel: 2, hNewToken: ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    using (tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate))
                    {
                        this.impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (this.impersonationContext != null)
                        {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(token);
        }
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Problem here is that WindowsImpersonationContext doesnt exist in .net core. Can anyone provide a code snippet which impersonates a user? Microsoft docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting isnt very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation):

> ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation. Apps run with the app's identity for all requests, using app pool or process identity. If the app should perform an action on behalf of a user, use `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated` or `RunImpersonatedAsync` in a terminal inline middleware in `Startup.Configure`.

```cs
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    try
    {
        var user = (WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity;

        await context.Response
            .WriteAsync($"User: {user.Name}\tState: {user.ImpersonationLevel}\n");

        WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
        {
            var impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            var message =
                $"User: {impersonatedUser.Name}\t" +
                $"State: {impersonatedUser.ImpersonationLevel}";

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            context.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.ToString());
    }
});
```