# How to configure connection string and IIS application pool Identity to enable access SQL Server with current windows credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sqlconnection

The question seems popular and repetitive, but I haven't found an answer that works for me in the last 24h, so don't blame me if I post it (again):

I have an IIS Server (ver.10) and an application that should connect to a SQL Server that runs on a different machine in our network. The credentials of the current AD Windows user should be passed to the SQL Connection String and grant access if that specific user is entitled to access.
The correct syntax for that scenario seems to be this:

```
"Data Source=MY-SQL-INSTANCE;Initial Catalog=MY-DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

If I do that, I get the SqlException "Login failed for user 'CORP\SERVERS0765$'" with CORP being the domain and SERVERS0765 being the server that runs the IIS. So for some reason the Identity of the IIS is passed, but not the identity of the one that called the app.

The Identity of the Application Pool is set to NetworkService, but I also tried all the other built-in-accounts. In my understanding it should be set to all "Domain\USERS" but then there is a password required which is never accepted.

---

Update: I picked this issue up again after some days and learned how to display the relevant parameters that defines your authentication:

```
Identity of the application Pool:      System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Is User Authenticated:                 User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString();

Authentication Type, if Authenticated: User.Identity.AuthenticationType;

User Name, if Authenticated:           User.Identity.Name;
```

That way I can actually see that switching on IIS ASP.NET Impersonation, changes the WindowsIdentity from the AppPool Identity to the User Identity.

```
Identity of the application Pool:      MyDomain\MyUserID

Is User Authenticated:                 True

Authentication Type, if Authenticated: Negotiate

User Name, if Authenticated:           MyDomain\MyUserID
```

Therefore it confuses me even more that if I launch the SQL Connection, the SQL Server replies: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
Anonymous Logon had been disabled!

Comment: You need to set it to Impersonate the user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/134ec8tc(v=vs.100) But apparently it doesn't work with ASP.NET Core https://stackoverflow.com/a/68579915/14868997 so you need to do the impersonation yourself

Comment: I get a "500 - Internal server error" once I added the impersonate tag in the web.config file. I'm using ASP.NET, not the Core version and I added the code that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/implement-impersonation mentions for "Impersonate the authenticating user in code"

Comment: Well you'll need to debug that and find out where it crashed. Is the user actually loggin in using Windows credentials (or Windows Single Sign On)?

Comment: @Charlieface : That only applies to http/2 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

Comment: The detail debugging says that the error most likely is due to "system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true". We are using Single-Sign-On

Comment: First get working with SQL Server Management Studio and use Windows Credentials in the login window.  Then after working in SSMS your connection string should use the same server\instance as the login window in SSMS.  The connection string should be Integrated Security=True;

Comment: For SSMS connection, the local and remote machines need to be in the same group and the user account needs to be in the group.  Best way of debugging is to use SSMS and check log file in the explorer under management.   The log file will indicate the user and group that was used to login and if the login passed or failed.

Comment: @jdweng Not the same group, just the same Active Directory domain. Or if in two domains (unusual) then the domain the SQL Server is in needs to have a trust relationship with the other. They both need line of sight to a Domain Controller. You also need to setup Constrained Delegation for the IIS AppPool user to the SQL Server machine. I'm not sure why you think HTTP/2 is relevant, it's Core vs not Core rather than the HTTP version.

Comment: 1. set application pool runs as domain user who has permissions to access SQL.
2. in iis (application/website ? you did not specified) - check basic settings - connect as - should be pass throw.

P.S> its not a good thing to get user to access to db.  make service account to access to db, and user will be authorized to call methods to make app call sql

Comment: @PowerMouse That's useless, it means all connections will use the same user. OP wants the webserver to impersonate the user who logs in, as if they are connecting to SQL Server.

Comment: in this case - make windows auth - on, anonuumis - off - that would be the user who connected to app.
in basic settings - connect as - make IUSR
application need to know user - and it should connect to db as IUSR - which is logged0in user

Comment: Go to IIS, click your website, select Authentication, enable ASP.NET Impersonation. IIS App Pool user needs to be a domain user, even a gMSA if possible, but SQL permissions are not necessary, you only need to setup either Constrained Delegation or Resource Based Constrained Delegation. In Powershell you can do `Get-ADComputer SqlServerMachineHere | Set-ADComputer -PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount "IISuser@yourdomain.com"`. You also need to set SPNs, but that happens automatically normally

Comment: @Charlieface: That sounded very promesing but unfortunatly once I enable ASP.NET Impersonation many of the other apps stopped working. For some it helped switching from Integrated to Classic, but other apps wouldn't run anymore. So I switched back the settings for ASP.NET Impersonation and wait for the users to leave before  continue.

Comment: @jdweng: the credentials to connect to the SQL Server are correct and I already checked them in an Excel Data Connection. This is all about the IIS Setup!

Comment: There is no difference in the connection string in Excel and c#.  If both excel and c# are on the same local machine and connecting to the same remote server there should be no issue.  You can check the log files in the SQL Server which will show the user/group of each login.  Try with excel and then with c#.  if you are connecting through a 3rd machine all three machines must be in the same group.  The group has to share the same password server.

Comment: This discussion went wild when the suggestions moved away from the narrow supported scenario. In short, to make things work the way you want, all machines must be in the same AD and Kerberos (not any other SSO) must be properly working to pass browser side user credentials to the server, so that your server side code on ASP.NET 4.x can impersonate and connect to the database. Anything away from that path is just noise. Involve your domain administrators and/or hire an experienced consultant. It's "popular and repetitive" simply because mistakes are too common to happen.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: @Charlieface: I enabled ASP.NET Impersonation but then couldn't run your Powershell command, as the SQL-Server can't be found for some reason (Cannot find an object with identity) although I can ping the hostname without any problems. With ASP.NET Impersonation enabled, the apps that are using the namespace "DirectoryServices" would throw exceptions that I couldn't solve so far.

Comment: I suggest you speak to your IT department to arrange the correct AD settings. Constrained delegation is complicated and can be insecure if not setup correctly. Are you sure the machine which SQL Server is on is actually joined to the AD domain (not just on the same network)? Are you sure you are using the machine's actual name and not a DNS alias?

Comment: @LexLi: All machines are in one Active Directory, we have Kerberos and SSO. Furthermore I set the identity in the ApplicationPool to my AD-Userid and nevertheless using the above mentioned connection string doesn't work for impersonation in this scenario. Something else is missing

Comment: Thank you very much for support and advise, I will try to involve the IT department of our company for that project; we from IT in the subsidiary probably have some limitations that hinder us to achive what I'm trying to set up.

Comment: @Charlieface I did some research of the state of my authentication/identity at the stage of connecting to the SQL Server. I added the result in an Update section of my original post.

Comment: Like I said, looks like an issue with Constrained Delegation (either Resource Based or classic). You need to set that up, so that IIS is allowed to pass the user's Kerberos ticket onwards to SQL Server. Also SQL Server needs to be running under a domain user or a gMSA (not the default which is a local machine user), and have an SPN set up correctly (but that should happen automatically once you have a domain user).

Comment: @Charlieface: Ok, now I got it. I don't have the necessary rights and can't even see the PKI folder in AD. So this project dies right here. Our organization never supported the web apps that I built for our Subsidiary over the years where I used a static SQL dummy account to link to the DataBases; on the other hand there are thousands of uncontrolled Excel's around with DataConections that do not require an additional Delegation in AD as the access rights are provided directly through the memberships of the AD user. No chance they will set this up for me. Thanks anyway for the explanation.